# Unable to boot or start system after install ubuntu 16

Tags: system-installation, boot-repair

I have installed Ubuntu 16 for the first time on my laptop and choose replace option while installing. After that I restart laptop and trying to start but I am getting following error:

[image]

I have tried to start with and without bootable pen drive but still getting same error and unable to start system now. No key is working on it. Please help.

Comment: What brand/model system? UEFI or BIOS install & then is system set to boot in that same boot mode as you installed. If you have Secure boot on, but installed in BIOS mode or UEFI without Secure boot then it may not have  anything to boot. See if UEFI secure boot setting is on. Shows install with screen shots. Both BIOS purple accessibility screen & UEFI black grub menu screen
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: Resolved : BIOS chip was off so inserted new one.